# How do I access status code and body inside my default template?

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

How do I display the HTTPResponse status code and body within a controller's action template? When I tried to set

```
$this->response->setStatusCode(400);
$this->response->setBody('invalid 2');
```

and return $this only what's on my action template is displayed? How do I access status code and body inside my default template?

Comment: don't you want to return `$this->response`?

Comment: I want to access the status code and body of response within my template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like that:

Add a method in your `Controller` to get the `SS_HTTPResponse` data:

```
public function Response()
{
  $response = new ArrayData(array(
    "StatusCode" => $this->getResponse()->getStatusCode(),
    "Body" => $this->getResponse()->getBody()
  ));

  return $response;
}
```

Then in your template you can use:

`$Response.StatusCode` and `$Response.Body`

Answer (score -1):

The template is used to form the response body. In your case, you set the response body as string.

There is no enough information about what you are trying to achieve.

If you want to create nice error page for particular code, then you should use `ErrorPage` type to create a special page, and use `$this->httpError(400);` in your controller. `ErrorPage` contais a field `ErrorCode` that is used to find existing error page by code, and may be used in the template, but usually you put the error code and message straight into `Content`.

Comment: What I wanted to do is access HttpResponse poperties inside my action template like in Laravel